# How does a command output can be accessed through UDEPLOY REST API

Tags: udeploy

I am using https://host/cli/componentProcessRequest/info/ to get the information about a component process request execution details. But this gives basic information not detailed like logs.

In this process we execute a shell script. I want to get the shell output log through REST API. Is there any way that i can achieve this ?